# Exception thrown while retrieving data from MongoDB with Android studio

Tags: android, mongodb, android-studio

In Android Studio I am trying to retrieve data from MongoDB through my application. For that I have written this piece of code (given below), but the application gives throws Exception and goes inside `catch`. So what can be the issue with this code? And how it can be solved?

**Code:**

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {

    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
    int responseCode;

    try {
        URL requestUrl = new URL("my url");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        connection.connect();

        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Status Code: " + responseCode);
        }

        else {
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
            if (contentLength > 0) {
                char[] buffer = new char[contentLength ];
                reader.read(buffer);
                Log.d(TAG, buffer);
                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(buffer));
            } else {
                String jsonData = isToString(stream);
                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            }

            Log.d(TAG, jsonResponse.toString(2));
            connection.disconnect();
            Toast.makeText(cntx, "Done Successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(cntx, "Error Occurred!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ", e);
    }


    return jsonResponse;
}
```

Comment: Please uncomment the line `Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ", e);`  and then paste the error so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: `Unfortunately, Project1 stopped`. this is error

Comment: OK, that is not very helpful, can you try printing the stacktrace at least? Like `e.printStackTrace();`